# How-to: Translate plural forms for themes/plugins with PoEdit

Tags: translation

As the title says: How would you translate...

- `_n()`
- `_n_noop()`
- `_nc()`
- `_nx()`
- `_nx_noop()`

...in your .mo files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Step 1

Open your file in [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php).

#### Step 2

Go to "*Catalogue*" » "*Settings*"

#### Step 3

Fill in "*Language*" **and** "*Country*" <sup>1)</sup>.

#### Step 4

Fill "*Pluralform*" (last field).

```
// For 2 plural forms
nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;

// For 3 plural forms (for e.g. russian), use:
nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 &amp;&amp; n%100!=11) ? 0 : ((n%10&gt;=2 &amp;&amp; n%10&lt;=4 &amp;&amp; (n%100&lt;10 || n%100&gt;=20)) ? 1 : 2);

// For 4 plural forms (for e.g. slovenian), use:
nplurals=4; plural=n%100==1 ? 0 : n%100==2 ? 1 : n%100==3 || n%100==4 ? 2 : 3;
```

#### Step 4

Go to the 3rd tab "*Keywords*".

Add the following list. <sup>2)</sup> Of course you have to extend to `1,2,3` for languages with three different plural forms and so on.

```
_n:1,2
_n_noop:1,2
_nx:1,2
_nx_noop:1,2
```

---

**Links**

- This [article](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/translating-wordpress-plugins-and-themes-dont-get-clever/) from Mark Jaquith may be interesting.
- [Heiko Rabe](http://www.code-styling.de/deutsch/wordcamp-vortrag-lokalisierung-als-pdf-download) explains where very well how to work with translation files (german language). He also offers an interesting PDF.

---

**Plugins**

[This Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) by (again) Heiko Rabe does a pretty good job with helping translating your plugin.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1) For e.g. UK & U.S.A. have different forms of "colour/color"</sup>

<sup>2) Every row goes in a single (new) entry.</sup>

Comment: _nc is deprecated in WP, it's the same as _n

Comment: "For e.g. UK & U.S.A. have different forms of "colour/color"" - And many many more. Americans like to spell many words with Z rather than S ;) Hence why the en_GB and en_US locals.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Saw `_c` depreacated and other stuff, but oversaw that one. Thanks.

Comment: "Of course you have to extend to 1,2,3 for languages with three different plural forms and so on." This is not true at all, gettext API remains the same regardless of the translation's language. [Read the docs.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [define the plural form](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/l10n/pluralforms) of the language your translating in your PO file (which gets compiled to MO).

For example English has two forms, so your PO file should have two "msgstr" definitions for each string with msgid_plural.

If you're using PoEdit it's easier, just paste the plural form definition in the catalog settings and you'll get extra fields for plural strings...

Comment: Wasn't that easy. You have to know how to setup the po file...