# _n() Single and Plural for search results?

Tags: localization

This code produces

> Search Results for "hello" - 1 articles "

```
<h3>Search Results for <?php echo'"'?>
    <?php /* Search Count */ 
    $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
    $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
    $count = $allsearch->post_count; 
    _e(''); 
    _e('<span class="search-terms">'); 
    echo $key; 
    _e('</span>'); 
    echo '"'; 
    _e(' - '); 
    echo $count . ' '; 
    _e('articles'); 
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</h3>
```

How can I make it `$single` and `$plural` for eg. "1 article" or "2 articles"?

Comment: Found the answer replace if "_e('articles');" with "($count!=1) { _e(‘articles’); } else { _e(‘article’); }"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using 'if' loop it's better to use special function:

```
<?php echo _n( 'article', 'articles', $count, 'my-plugin-domain' ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n

Comment: +1 This is the proper way to do it. Unfortunately I don't think Poedit parses this correctly though.

Comment: @StephenHarris I can remember creating singular and plural translations in Poedit. Don't believe it should be a problem.

Comment: Thank you! Why do you have to use  "$count, 'my-plugin-domain'"

Comment: @Josh The `$count` parameter is so the function knows which argument to use: singular or plural. The last parameter is the [translation domain](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Comment: Just [take a look at this Q on how to setup & translate plural forms with POEdit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/how-to-translate-plural-forms-for-themes-plugins-with-poedit).