# Add custom Facebook share link with share count and variable text

Tags: posts, facebook

I'm trying to do this in a news site homepage.

[image: news site homepage]

The part I'm struggling with is the Facebook share link text.
It should:

- count the share/link of the specific post
- hide the number is it's 0
- write "share!" if it has 0 share
- write "shared 1 time" if it has 1 share
- write "n shares" if it has more than 1 shares.

The text is arbitrary, I would like to be able to control it.

I found this code to get the likes count:

```
function get_likes($url) {
 $json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
 $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
 return intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
}
```

And I managed to use it to get the actual share count:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">
 <?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo get_likes("$url"); ?> shares</a>
```

Now the difficult part would be how to control the text the same way it's controlled in "comments_number":

```
comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' );
```

Any hint?

Comment: This is almost the same question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47220/n-single-and-plural-for-search-results

Comment: Uhm, I could be wrong but it seems that question address how to count Wordpress stored values and not external one, isn't it? I imagine the solution would involve some sort of calculation in the get_likes($url) function.

Comment: get_likes only returns a number. So returning the appropriate text is all that is missing and that is covered in the answer I linked to. Unless I got something wrong...

Comment: I found a different answer that did the trick! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286964/how-do-i-change-the-singular-plural-on-comment-to-comments-on-facebooks-num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution thanks to this answer:
[How do I change the singular/plural on “comment” to “comments” on Facebook's number of comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286964/how-do-i-change-the-singular-plural-on-comment-to-comments-on-facebooks-num)

Here is how I solved without the  tag, using the code I was already working for, this goes into function.php

```
function get_likes($url) {
   $json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
   $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
   $count = intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
   if ($count == 0) {
     echo "share!";
   } elseif ($count == 1) {
     echo "shared 1 time";
   } else {
   echo "$count shares";
   }
}
```

and this in the template

```
<?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo get_likes($url); ?>
```